# Generating unique random values along with a series - creating test data for postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to generate a unique random() number for each row to be inserted into this table. Can anyone show me how I can generate the number and assign it to the `dis` field?

Thanks very much!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lat_longs;

CREATE TABLE lat_longs (
  id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  pos             REAL NOT NULL
  dis             REAL NOT NULL
);

insert into lat_longs(pos)
select g.position
from generate_series(0, 100, 0.001) as g(position);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `random()`:

```
insert into lat_longs (pos, dis)
    select g.position, random()
    from generate_series(0, 100, 0.001) as g(position);
```

This produces a number between 0 and 1.  If you want a number in a particular range, use arithmetic.  For instance, between -180 and 180:

```
random() * 360 - 180
```

I should also say that `random()` does not guarantee that there are no duplicates.  But it is very, very, very unlikely to occur.

Comment: And if it were absolutely essential they be unique (for some not readily apparent reason), he could always pass it through a DISTINCT ON.